# Powershell search through two lines

Tags: powershell, lines

I have following Input lines in my notepad file.

example 1 :

```
//UNION TEXT=firststring,FRIEND='ABC,Secondstring,ABAER'
```

example 2 :

```
//UNION TEXT=firststring,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
//            FRIEND='ABC,SecondString,ABAER'
```

Basically, one line can span over two or three lines. If last character is `,` then it is treated as continuation character.

In example 1 - Text is in one line. 
In example 2 - same Text is in two lines.

In example 1, I can probably write below code. However, I do not know how to do this if 'Input text' spans over two or three lines based on continuation character `,`

```
$result = Get-Content $file.fullName | ? { ($_ -match firststring) -and ($_ -match 'secondstring')}
```

I think I need a way so that I can search text in multipl lines with '-and' condition. something like that...

Thanks!

Comment: So basically all you want is to convert example 2 to example 1 (i.e. remove the `newline` from example 2? Anyway, just do: `$result = ((Get-Content $file.fullName) -join "") | ? { ($_ -match firststring) -and ($_ -match 'secondstring')}`

Comment: Thanks but This isn't working for me. 'Example 1' and 'example 2' are in a Huge file and join is concatenating the entire file as one. I need something to " perform search of 'secondstring' if previous line contained 'firststring'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the entire content of the file, join the continued lines, and then split the text line-wise:

```
$text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\path\to\your.txt")
$text -replace ",`r`n", "," -split "`r`n" | ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but it also doesn't seem to work. The file remains as it is. It only works if I convert the 'Example 1' input into 'Example 2' manually.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". My sample code doesn't write the changes back to the file, it just prepares the input for further processing. Also, it's supposed to work only on example 2. What about example 1 would you want to modify?

Comment: Actually notepad file in which 'Example 1' and 'Example 2' is present  doesn't have   `n   at end of each line. I mean your code works perfectly if I introduce a `n  at end of 'firststring,'. However, it doesn't work if I run your code on my Input file. Sorry for confusion and Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm confused. The escape sequence `\`r\`n` stands for a carriage return `\`r` followed by a line feed `\`n`. Windows uses these two characters for encoding line breaks in text files. If your files don't contain this character sequence, their line breaks must be encoded either Unix-style (just `\`n`) or (classic) MacOS-style (just `\`r`). Could you provide a sample file for download somewhere?

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. If I do following it works :  $text -replace ",\s*`n", "," -split "\s*`n".

Comment: If that works, but my original suggestion doesn't, then your file has either Unix-style line breaks (just `\`n`) or trailing whitespace (spaces or tabs) at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the full content as one String
$content = Get-Content -Path $file.fullName -Raw
# join continued lines, split content and filter
$content -replace '(?<=,)\s*' -split '\r\n' -match 'firststring.+secondstring'
```

Comment: -Maybe I am not doing it right. this doesn't seem to work. -Raw option isn't working with my version of Powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If file is large and you want to avoid loading entire file into memory you might want to use good old .NET ReadLine:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("test.txt")
try {
    $sb = New-Object -TypeName "System.Text.StringBuilder";

    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }

        if ($line.EndsWith(','))
        {
            [void]$sb.Append($line)
        }
        else
        {
            [void]$sb.Append($line)
            # You have full line at this point.
            # Call string match or whatever you find appropriate.
            $fullLine = $sb.ToString()
            Write-Host $fullLine
            [void]$sb.Clear()
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

If file is not large (let's say < 1G) Ansgar Wiechers answer should do the trick.